# TinyMCE iOS bug. New line gets the cursor beyond the viewable area

Tags: ios, return, tinymce, enter

I'm currently using tinyMCE as a rich text editor for my iOS application. It works great in desktop but when I tested it in iOS platform, the behavior is different. Whenever I insert a new line by pressing enter and it goes beyond the maximum height of my RTE, the cursor gets beyond the visible area. The expectation is that the area should automatically scroll down once the line is beyond the visible area when pressing Enter.

Kindly advise.